# Removing header and footer when printing

Tags: printing

I need to remove the header and footer (date, page title, url) inserted by the browser when printing. I know it can be done on the client by configuring the browser, however this not an option. I know everyone says it is not possible.. But there must be a way to do this with javascript or some server side coding or something else? Does anyone know of any kind of solution?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe this is possible in almost any scenario.  The information is added BY THE CLIENT.  Thus if there is no way for you to configure your clients there is no way to remove the information.

My best advice would be to offer the information as a PDF rather than a page that the browser modifies.